# In pandas DataFrame, how can I store a specific value from a column into a variable, and then subsequently remove that value from the column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sort of new to using pandas in Python for data visualization, and have this code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/ephemeralhappiness/Desktop/Packet/Fake Data.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B'])
print(df)
```

So I have created this DataFrame from reading Fake Data.csv with columns A and B. For example, how would I retrieve the 5th value of column A so I can store it into the variable. How would I remove the 5th value of column A?

I tried the following code for my first question:

```
print(df.iat(4,0))
```

In theory, this should return the fifth value of column A, but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: '_AtIndexer' object is not callable
```

[Before/after picture but the 5th value removed from column A needs to be stored in a variable first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Igh.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! What do you want to happen to the rest of the row in column B, or what should A be replaced with? Showing the output you want as well as whatever `Fake Data.csv` would be helpful.

Comment: Do you want the 5th value to be replaced for `null` or you want to delete the entire row?

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks! Let's say I remove the 5th value from column A, I would want all values following the 5th value to shift up (e.g. the 6th value becomes the 5th, etc etc). For simplicity, Fake Data.csv is just a table with columns A and B where column A has elements of all odd numbers less than 100, and column B has elements of all even numbers less than 100.

Comment: @vmouffron I would want to delete the entire row, but only after saving the value.

Comment: @ggorlen I updated my question with a before/after picture

Comment: [Text is better than pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors),  but thanks.

Comment: What should happen with the last value of column A, since that doesn't exist a row below it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this might work:

`a = df.iloc[4, 0]
df.iloc[4:,0] = df.iloc[4:,0].shift(-1)`

Answer (score 0):

Please use square brackets *[* for `iat` statement. For example `print(df.iat[4,0])`.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question. If you just want to comment on the author's code, please wait until you have 50 reputation.

Comment: @ggorlen Sir, not commenting, just pointing towards the source of the error. I hope that solved the author's problem.

Comment: I see, thanks. It doesn't remove the row, though, which is what OP wants: "I want all values following the 5th value to shift up (e.g. the 6th value becomes the 5th, etc etc". Granted, it's not obvious from the question itself.